# Pass a variable or value in async await API vue js/laravel

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, async-await, fetch-api

I have an API and what I want is to pass the value of the email, to see if the email exist or not from the API, but every time I run it and check the console log, it returns undefined? Anyone here can give a better code or approach, I want to do it with fetch, not axios please.

```js
const email = this.loginbus.loginemail

await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin', { email: email })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Also tried this, but it's not working:

```js
let result = new Request('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
  method: 'GET',
  body: JSON.stringify({ email: email })
})

result = await result.json()
console.log(result)
```

Laravel Code controller:

```php
public function checklogin(Request $request) {
  //return $request->input('email');

  $getVerify = Makatibuspartner::where('email', $request->email)->select('email_verified_at')->first();           
        
  if (!$getVerify){
    return ["status" => 400, "error" => "Please enter an email/registered email"];
  } else if ($getVerify && is_null($getVerify->email_verified_at)) {
    return ["status" => 400, "error" => "Not yet Verified"];    
  } else {
    return ["status" => 200, "message" => "Verified"];
  }  
}
```

Can somebody give me the right way to pass a variable or value of email to the API?

Comment: `fetch(...).then(response => { console.log(response); return response.json(); }).then(data => {...})`

Comment: fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin',  JSON.stringify({ email })) any idea to revise this code? json stringify part?

Comment: It needs to be a query parameter: `fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin?email=' + encodeURIComponent(email))`

Answer (score 1):

GET does not have body. use query parameters.
and you don't need to use await when you use promises

promises:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin?' + qs.stringify({ email }))
    .then((response) => {}, (error) => {});
```

async/await:

```
try {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin?' + qs.stringify({ email }));  
} 
catch (error) { }
```

your second example is incorrect as well

```
const req = new Request('http://localhost:8000/api/login?' + qs.stringify({ email }), {
  method: 'GET'
})

const response = await fetch(req)

const result = await response.json()
console.log(result)
```

if you do not want to use qs use this instead:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin?email=' + encodeURIComponent(email);
```

Comment: Its not right, it says qs is not defined

Comment: fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin',  JSON.stringify({ email })) any idea to revise this code? json stringify part?

Comment: qs is an external library. npm install it. it will help you to generate query string (qs). https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs . if you don't want to use it you can have something like this: 'http://localhost:8000/api/checklogin?email=' + encodeURIComponent(email);